# How can i make collection.sort(list) as thread safe without using synchronize keyword

Tags: multithreading

How can i make collection.sort(list) as thread safe without using synchronize block/keyword

```
public class IdealPriceStrategy implements ICalculate {

    public BigDecimal calculate(List<BigDecimal> prices) {
        BigDecimal idealPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        if(null!=prices){
            if(prices.size() > 5) {
                int size= prices.size();
                Collections.sort(prices);
                prices = prices.subList(2, size-2);
                idealPrice = new PriceBL(prices).getAverage().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.2));
            }
        }
        return idealPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can warp the list in an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) wrapper. Then all access to the list will by synchronized. But if your goal is to make `calculate` thread-safe, then this won't help.

Comment: But when i am going to warp the list in an unmodifiable wrapper.then i will not able to do sorting.
 prices =Collections.unmodifiableList(prices);
  Collections.sort(prices);

I want sorted list too.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) wrapper. Sorry!